# Asp net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Boa noite, é uma dúvida simples, nem sei se aqui é o lugar certo pra perguntar isso (se não e puderem me falar onde eu já agradeço) mas estou querendo aprender a usar o Asp.Net Identity e encontrei esse tutorial do Eduardo Pires https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKop7c_OdR0 no Youtube
Porém o projeto que estou desenvolvendo eu utilizo o Asp Core, queria saber se o Identity no Asp.Net Mvc é muito diferente do Core, pra saber se vale a pena eu fazer essa aula, e se for diferente e alguém souber me dizer onde posso encontrar um tutorial agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acredito que a maior diferença seja a forma que é configurado e injetado na aplicação.

Você pode aprender como utilizá-lo através do próprio site da microsoft:

[ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Também tem um minicurso do Macoratti:

[Minicurso ASP.NET Core Identity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GWdT9ZWNZs)

O próprio Eduardo tem um projeto no Github que faz uso dessa tecnologia:

[Equinox Project](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject)

Talvez de quebra você queira já criar um servidor OpenID/OAuth2 para fazer autenticação e autorização:

[IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4)